# ORACLE Sort Alphabetically Upper A, Lower a, numerics

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am sorting with Oracle version 12 with the following NLS parameters

- NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
- NLS_SORT BINARY
- NLS_COMP BINARY

Eg. " 1Andy"," Andy","Andy","andy","Aaron","Bob"

> SELECT name from employee order by name

result:
" 1Andy"," Andy","Aaron","Andy","Bob","andy"

if I change the NLS_SORT to WEST_EUROPEAN, it is suppose to be " 1Andy"," Andy","Aaron","Andy","andy","Bob"
but the result is  " 1Andy"," Andy","andy","Aaron","Andy","Bob"
where andy even though is lower case goes in the middle.

> SELECT name from employee order by  NLSSORT(name ,'NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5lbi.png)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can have case-insensitive sorting by adding _ci the the collation spec: west_european_ci. That being said, it seems in west_european sorting spec, number come after alpha chars. Here's what I get with your data using different collation specs

```
SQL> with dt as (
  2  select ' 1Andy' cv from dual
  3  union all
  4  select ' Andy' from dual
  5  union all
  6  select '1Andy' from dual
  7  union all
  8  select 'Andy' from dual
  9  union all
 10  select 'andy' from dual
 11  union all
 12  select 'Aaron' from dual
 13  union all
 14  select 'Bob' from dual)
 15  select *
 16  from dt
 17  order by cv;

CV    
------
 1Andy
 Andy
1Andy
Aaron
Andy
Bob
andy

7 rows selected. 

SQL> 
SQL> with dt as (
  2  select ' 1Andy' cv from dual
  3  union all
  4  select ' Andy' from dual
  5  union all
  6  select '1Andy' from dual
  7  union all
  8  select 'Andy' from dual
  9  union all
 10  select 'andy' from dual
 11  union all
 12  select 'Aaron' from dual
 13  union all
 14  select 'Bob' from dual)
 15  select *
 16  from dt
 17  order by nlssort(cv,'NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN');

CV    
------
 Andy
 1Andy
Aaron
Andy
andy
Bob
1Andy

7 rows selected. 

SQL> 
SQL> with dt as (
  2  select ' 1Andy' cv from dual
  3  union all
  4  select ' Andy' from dual
  5  union all
  6  select '1Andy' from dual
  7  union all
  8  select 'Andy' from dual
  9  union all
 10  select 'andy' from dual
 11  union all
 12  select 'Aaron' from dual
 13  union all
 14  select 'Bob' from dual)
 15  select *
 16  from dt
 17  order by nlssort(cv,'NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN_ci');

CV    
------
 Andy
 1Andy
Aaron
Andy
andy
Bob
1Andy

7 rows selected.
```